# AngularJS - RangeError: 'Maximum call stack size exceeded after' application start

Tags: javascript, angularjs

After running AngularJS app in by NetBeans error mentioned in title appears. I can't see any points where stack is overloaded, as you see I only initialize two variables for login form handling (i'm at the start of my AngularJS adventure). Can it be some hardware issue or I'm making some unconscious mistake here?

error :

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at c (public_html/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:115:232)
    at http://localhost:8383/LoginJS/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:115:506
    at q (public_html/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:7:355)
    at Object.error (public_html/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:115:475)
    at http://localhost:8383/LoginJS/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:89:12
    at ra (public_html/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:69:475)
    at xa (public_html/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:58:270)
    at xa (public_html/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:58:402)
    at ba (public_html/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:56:264)
    at A.link (public_html/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js:7:224) (13:52:05:371 | error)
```

app.js

```
angular.module('myapp', ['ngRoute']).config(function($routeProvider) {
         $routeProvider
                 .when('/', {
                     templateUrl: 'index.html'
         })
                 .when('/dashboard', {
                     templateUrl: 'dashboard.html'
         })
                 .otherwise(({
                     redirectTo: '/'
         }));
});
```

loginCtrl.js

```
angular.module('myapp').controller('loginCtrl', function($scope, $location) {
    $scope.submit = function() {
        var username = $scope.username;
        var password = $scope.password;

        if($scope.username == 'admin' && $scope.password == 'admin') {
            $location.path('/dashboard');
        }
    };
})
```

index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/loginCtrl.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="myapp">
        <div ng-view></div>
        <div ng-controller="loginCtrl">
            <form action="/" id="login">
                Username: <input type="text" name="username" id="username" ng-model="username"><br>
                Password: <input type="password" name="password" id="password" ng-model="password"><br>
                <button type="button" ng-click="submit()">Login</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

dashboard.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
         <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    </head>
    <body ng-app="myapp">
        <div ng-view></div>
        some text
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because of you load all script files for both page and load `index.html` for `'/'` path that circular loading `index.html` page that's why you got this error.

In `dashboard.html` no need to load your script files again just write your information nothing else . And your login form move to another page like `login.html` and refer this page for path `"/"`.

like:

route provider:

```
.when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'login.html'
 })
```

`index.html` page

```
<body ng-app="myapp">
    <h1>Welcome </h1>
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
```

`login.html` page

```
<div ng-controller="loginCtrl">
      <form action="/" id="login">
          Username: <input type="text" name="username" id="username" ng-model="username"><br>
          Password: <input type="password" name="password" id="password" ng-model="password"><br>
          <button type="button" ng-click="submit()">Login</button>
      </form>
 </div>
```

and `dashboard.html`

```
<div ng-controller="CtrlName"> //ng-controller="CtrlName" if need ctrl and also can use ctrl in route provider
   <h2> Dashboard page</h2>
   // all of your information's 
</div>
```

It may will work perfectly

Comment: I modified dashboard.html according to your suggestion and error didn't dissapear

Comment: Have you any function that made circular reference ? and can try by shifting login information to another html page like `login.html` and for `'/'` path refer that page as a `templateUrl` instead of `index.html` @Mike

Comment: Thank you, now it's fine @shaishab roy

Comment: Thank you so much, my problem was in the `.otherwise()` method. That redirected me to `index.html` again and again making stack exceed.

Answer (score 0):

use script control on direction for load your script files again just write your information nothing else . And your login form move to another page like `login.html` and refer this page for path `"/"`.